# Swift 4 doesn't pickup single quotes ("\'") in switch

Tags: swift, switch-statement, swift4

I recently downloaded the Xcode beta and am coding in swift 4.

I created a switch like so:

```
func key(cipher: Character) -> Int{
        let someCharacter: Character = cipher
        switch someCharacter {
        case "\'":
            return 27
        case "\"":
            return 28 
        default:
            return -1  //error
        } 
}
```

I want to be able to input ' and get 27. How do I do this??

Edit:
I also have a button:

```
@IBAction func encrypt(_ sender: Any) { 
    inputedValues = String(input.text!)!
    let index = inputedValues.index(inputedValues.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
        var number = key(cipher: inputedValues[index]) }
```

Comment: It´s working fine if you only test the `switch`, make sure that everything is ok with the `Character`.

Comment: Your code should work fine – could you please provide a [mcve]? Although note that you don't actually need to escape `'`, you could also say `case "'"`.

Comment: for some reason when I input " ' " (no spaces) I get -1

Comment: `key(cipher: "'")` returns 27 with your code.

Comment: Please show the output of `print(">\(inputedValues)<")`

Comment: it prints the following: 1'

Comment: That *cannot* be the output from that print statement, please check the updated version. –  And what does `print(someCharacter)` in your function show? (Do people still learn how to *debug* nowadays ??)

Comment: The `print(inputedValues[index])` prints the following: '

Comment: It would help greatly if you included both your input string and the expected output so that we could see what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This worked using Xcode 9 Beta and Swift 4 in Playground.
Try this:

```
func key(_ cipher: Character) -> Int{
    let someCharacter: Character = cipher
    switch someCharacter {
    case "'":
        return 27
    default:
        return -1  //error
    }
}

let input = "1'"
let index = input.characters.index(input.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let cipher = input[index] // Returns second character

key(cipher) //Output is 27
```

Comment: There appears to be a color syntax issue with the last comment in my answer  '//Output is 27' ...

Comment: Did you check if that makes a difference?

Comment: I have a let index = inputedValues.index(inputedValues.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
let number = key(cipher: inputedValues[index])

Comment: @Zac: As mentioned above: Please add a [mcve] to your **question.**

Comment: for some reason when I input "1'" I get -1, but its supposed to take the second character

Comment: If you input "1'" it will output -1 as "1'" is not a set case. Thus, it uses the default output. I recommend adding a case "1'" that returns your desired output.

Comment: let index = inputedValues.index(inputedValues.startIndex, offsetBy: 1); let number = key(cipher: inputedValues[index]) finds the second character in the string then uses the switch to output the appropriate value

Answer (score -1):

Partial Fix:

```
func key(cipher: Character) -> Int{
        let someCharacter: Character = cipher
        switch someCharacter {
        case "’": //not "\'" or "'"
            return 27
        case "\"":
            return 28 
        default:
            return -1  //error
        }
}
```

Comment: This was only a partial fix, i still don't get the right return value if index = inputedValues.index(inputedValues.startIndex, offsetBy: 1) (where offset is greater than 0)